# Проблема с rxtx

Tags: java, исключения, port, raspberry-pi, rxtx

Пользуюсь Intellij idea.

Есть проект. В нем используется библиотека `rxtx-2.2.jar`.
Но при запуске приложения на Raspberry pi вылезают ошибки:

```
  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
no rxtxSerial in java.library.path thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver

    Exception in thread "Thread-3" Exception in thread "Thread-4" 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier
```

При этом, `librxtx-java` установлен в системе, а библиотека присутствует в проекте (и `CommPortIdentifier` в ней, соответственно, тоже).

Что же делать?

Comment: попробуйте явно путь к каталогу, в котором лежат `rxtxSerial.so` указать при запуске, типа `java -Djava.library.path=/path/to/lib-dir your.app.MainClass`

Comment: @zRrr, не помогло.